# api call test from github actions get 403 and seems not reaching to API deployed to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-api-gateway

I wrote a test using Jest and Frisby to call an API and I can confirm it works locally. I tried execute it via Github runner so that this test can be ran on every PR.

However, Github action result shows a 403 HTTP error. Moreover, I cannot find the API access log in AWS CloudWatch. This means something other than WAF is blocking the API call from Github actions.

Can anyone list what could be the reason causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your Github action has the appropriate conditions to do a request to the API successfully? (CORS, API-key, authorization, etc.)